# How can put image back of paints which i drew?

Tags: processing

The thing what I want to make is similar to paint program.
The problem is when I draw some lines(Not just lines. Whole things I drew are included in this case.), those lines only drawn back of a image I put in before I draw that.

At first, I thought it was just problem of code's order. But it wasn't.

I just want draw some lines on the image like paint program.
Like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uEsb.jpg)

Comment: Can you please rephrase ? It's heard to understand what you're trying to ask. Is it something similar to layers in Photoshop where you draw on top of the image, but the original image layer underneath is unaffected by the strokes on the layer above ?

Comment: yes, but when I save image, it should be saved 'affected'(I wonder it is right expression because of lack of knowledge about processing.......)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paint into a separate "layer" using [PGraphics](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html).
Once you initialise an instance you can use the typical drawing methods within `beginDraw()` / `endDraw()` (as the reference example suggests).

The only thing left is to save the final image which is simple enough using [save()](https://processing.org/reference/save_.html)

Here's a modified example of **Examples > Basics > Image > LoadDisplay** which uses a separate PGraphics instance to draw into as the mouse is dragged and saves the final image when the `s` key is pressed:

```
/**
 * Based on Examples > Basics > Image > Load and Display 
 * 
 * Images can be loaded and displayed to the screen at their actual size
 * or any other size. 
 */

PImage img;  // Declare variable "a" of type PImage
// reference to layer to draw into
PGraphics paintLayer;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  // The image file must be in the data folder of the current sketch 
  // to load successfully
  img = loadImage("moonwalk.jpg");  // Load the image into the program

  // create a separate layer to draw into
  paintLayer = createGraphics(width,height);
}

void draw() {
  // Displays the image at its actual size at point (0,0)
  image(img, 0, 0);
  // Displays the paint layer
  image(paintLayer,0,0);
}

void mouseDragged(){
  // use drawing commands between beginDraw() / endDraw() calls
  paintLayer.beginDraw();
  paintLayer.line(mouseX,mouseY,pmouseX,pmouseY);
  paintLayer.endDraw();
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(key == 's'){
    saveFrame("annotated-image.png");
  }
}
```

Comment: It is exactly what I want to do!
And link about PGraphic's reference was big help
Thank you for your help!